# Why are there no hyper links to the PDF's in the docuent library?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint document library with PDFs that I can select and click the download button to download, but they are no hyperlinks. There is another library on the site with hyperlinked documents but I can't see why these work and the other ones don't. What sm I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to modify the view to include the Name/Title with link to document column.

[image]